# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Movies & TV Stack Exchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: So, now can we expect graduation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why use commentator in TV broadcasts of sports?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17177/why-use-commentator-in-tv-broadcasts-of-sports)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does the title Silver Linings Playbook mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16991/what-does-the-title-silver-linings-playbook-mean)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How are audio tracks censored on TV?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16982/how-audio-tracks-are-censored-on-tv)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [About Zoe Barnes in the second season of House of Cards](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17433/about-zoe-barnes-in-the-second-season-of-house-of-cards)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What was the virtual reality research that was used to produce the movie A.I.?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/what-was-the-virtual-reality-research-that-was-used-to-produce-the-movie-a-i)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Looking for the name of a SF or horror movie - bunker spreading vine/fungus](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/looking-for-the-name-of-a-sf-or-horror-movie-bunker-spreading-vine-fungus)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [People with serious life threatening disease fight gangsters in a bar](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17122/people-with-serious-life-threatening-disease-fight-gangsters-in-a-bar)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Why didn't the key word trigger the hypnosis on the first incident?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17468/why-didnt-the-key-word-trigger-the-hypnosis-on-the-first-incident)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Upto what extent do foreign sitcoms/drama shows exhibits 'real culture' of those countries?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16920/upto-what-extent-do-foreign-sitcoms-drama-shows-exhibits-real-culture-of-those)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Was J. Gatsby a shallow, superficial man?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/was-j-gatsby-a-shallow-superficial-man)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed that sometimes users -- especially new users asking their first question -- will use the comment section for a given answer to say something like "That's the answer I was looking for, thanks" but will not accept the answer (probably just not realizing that they should.) Then the user moves on from the site, having got what they needed -- while the correct answer sits there without getting accepted.

Is there any way mods could accept answers in these situations? Here's an example: 
[Movie about a father and his 2 sons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18350/movie-about-a-father-and-his-2-sons)

Comment: This has always been a problem with SE sites and I'm not sure mods can do anything about it. It is hard to define when it is actually valid for a mod to accept an answer for another user's account and that would probably be too much power (I'm not saying mods are going to misuse that, just that it's hard to say when this is really 100% applicable). There is just nothing to be done than properly informing the users about how it works and hoping for them to internalize it. As much as we *would like* users to post "good" questions and answers, we *would like* them to know how the site works.

Comment: Moderators have no ability to accept an answer on behalf of another user.

Comment: @iandotkelly http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60212/221866

Comment: @BleedingFingers - err, I just want to be sure I understand what you are saying, as the post you link-to here makes the same point I make, I think :)

Comment: @iandotkelly nahh, we are on the same page. Just dropped the link here as ref and for further reading on the matter. shog9's takes are usually interesting and provide good perspective. :)

Comment: @BleedingFingers - cool, thanks - just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I'd missed.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the best self-evaluation I've seen here - no terrible questions, even the identification ones were detailed.

I was even quite harsh on one by making it as 'needs improvement' as I thought it was not the strongest answer.

Comment: I screwed up and marked a question with very terrible grammar as the best value.  Every single question stood out as requiring some form of editing for readability.

Answer (score 2):

I found myself stating most of the answers were of very high quality.

As this site is still in Beta, I have the attitude that there are many simplistic questions which are getting asked. As long as these fit the scope of the site, I'm okay with this as I think it will lead to Movies & TV becoming a definitive reference point for these materials in future.

However, one things I have noticed is that whilst a site like Stack Overflow has a collection of *rookie* questions which have been definitively answered once and now all subsequent questions of that ilk are marked as duplicate, this site can't really do that. This is because there are *so* many movies and tv shows out there and *rookie* questions can be asked about any of them.

So whilst I *am* happy answering these questions and making Movies & TV a definitive reference point online, there are a large number of questions being posted currently which can be easily answered with just a few google searches.