# 1111 days in beta: Where do we stand?

Tags: support, graduation

I'd like to use the fact that the site is now elevenhundredeleven days old as an opportunity to enquire a little **status update** from the higher powers, if possible.

First of all, while I'm aware that there are still some things to resolve and some questions to answer, I think the site is doing largely well and is on a good way to a full-fledged member of the SE-community, as also evident from [our stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies-tv). As a result of this, we have been announced to be [**slated for graduation**](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1267/49) about 7 months ago (with the actual decision made about 11 months ago, if I'm informed correctly), effectively waiting for a design to be made and the graduation to complete therewith.

However, nothing really happened since then, which is a little bit off-putting, seeing that it is only the **design that seems to be the limiting factor** (even if SE is largely of the opinion that this is the only relevant part of graduation anyway). The rather temporary nature of that intermediate state was to my knowledge also the reason why SE didn't intervene when our moderator asked about the problem of only a **single active moderator** about a year ago, a situation we're back to for quite a while now. Now, I don't want to come here to whine (or at least not only ;-)). I know that SE aren't sorcerors and have enough things to do, and they're doing a great a job afterall. I also know that SE can't lay all their internals completely open. I neither want minutely updates nor come across as impatient. But the complete lack of any kind of status update makes me have to ask for at least some kind of clarification on the matter.

I have gathered some information from a [comment (!) over on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237472/where-have-the-site-self-evaluations-gone#comment778914_237588) about 4 months ago, which said the ordered graduation queue to contain:

> Salesforce, Expression Engine, Anime, Computer Science, Japanese, Cryptography, **Movies**, Blender, and English Language Learners.

From which in the meantime [one graduated about 3 months ago](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/740) and another [one is about to do so currently](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1281), positioning us at the currently **5th** place in the queue (assuming it's still relevant). So *if* the graduation frequency continues that way, we'd still have **at least another year to go**.

I would thus hereby like to enquire at least ***some* kind of information about the current status**, be it only that everything goes on like before and we just have to be patient or simply that nothing about the process can be disclosed at all. Is the graduation frequency expected to remain at its current pace or is it expected to gather a bit more momentum? Have we been removed from the graduation queue for whatever reason? Is my above information about the structure of the queue still correct at all? Do whiny meta rants result in suspension of any graduation efforts? ...

Otherwise I'll ask again at the 2222 mark. ;-)

Comment: My current score is 1879. I'll hit Moderator Privileges at 2000. As soon as that happens, I expect us to go out of Beta, so I'll have to earn another 8000 points to re-attain moderator privileges. I expect this to happen next week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you already figured out, you have already been slated for graduation, and the backlog for graduation is… not small.

I sent a request to bump Movies SE to the top of the design list about two months ago. I know that such delays can be annoying (I share your frustration). But beyond that, I don't have an estimate on how much longer it will be.

***Update:*** It looks like we're bringing on a new designer whose first order of business is to complete the Movies SE design. I saw a preview of his work and it is pretty slick. ETA is early-ish next year (February), so unless there are any further delays, I am anticipating launching the graduation around that time.

Comment: To be clear, it wasn't really a moderator election I wanted to propose here, let alone press the site to the top of the queue at the expense of some other poor site. But thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Ohhh....great, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Legendary! Thanks

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Oh come on now. You're long overdue a mod hat. I don't think many would argue with that :)

Comment: The design discussion is now posted: [Site design for Movies SE](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1501/1876)

Answer (score 4):

> **Where do we stand?**
>
> As you already said stats are good :-
>
> - 10.9 questions per day
>     **Excellent**
> - 93% answered **Excellent**
> - 578 avid users **Excellent**
>
>   - 10,627 total
>   - 150 users with 200+ rep (currently 578 users with 200+ rep)
>   - 10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently 71 users with 2,000+ rep)
>   - 5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently 51 users with 3,000+ rep)
> - 1.7 answer ratio
>     ***Okay***
> - 20,094 visits/day
>     **Excellent**
>
> Everything is excellent except Answer ration, which is also ok.

Now my concerns are:-

Are we able to moderate site with single mod?

Yes,

- we are easily able to close down crappy questions.
- we are good in editing badly written question and answer.
- we handle review bar on time.
  and so and so.

Weak points

- meta activity is bit low.
- due to one mod, responsibility on him became heavy and he can't take an off otherwise we will ping him to death :P....jokes apart he is doing great job.

But still overall i think if its going to take one more year to graduate then SE team need to assign us atleat more pro-temp mods. Every site have atleast three so why not us?

So we should get an election or SE team can appoint two more mod as per activities. Even i can give few recommendation :)

Comment: I'm still unhappy at the growing amount of identify-this versus other questions. I've only done a small amount of querying on this, but they are growing and if the trend continues will outnumber the *other* questions. I'd love some guidance on how many askers of identify-this are sticking around too, e.g. how many OPs have more than one question or answer.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Well, if the situation worsenes, I'll definitely take more serious measures, like proposing a dedicated SE site for identification. But until that we'll just have to try and be stricter about the quality of those questions to try to control it. Currently we're still at 28% (though, it also was 25% or even 20% once).

Comment: @AndrewMartin The problem of a dying non-ID userbase is also one I'd have liked to adress with at least a *little* more progress afterall.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I ran some queries to see the increase yearly, and it does show that if you look at just the last two years, the amount of identify-this questions in proportion to everything rises significantly. But yeah, I'll let a mod tackle this further. I've just no time right now.